# Manipulating JSON data to create javascript array of lat/lngs in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use lat/lng values retrieved from MySQL to create an array of waypoints for use in the GMaps API. I have the code below but with my limited javascript knowledge am struggling to push this retrieved data into a javascript array to define as the waypoints data.

I've looked at a few online examples and so far I have managed to get a parsing script to retrieve the data with no problems and call this within the page I have the maps instantiated on:

```
makeRequest('parsedata.php', function(data) {

            var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                displayLocation(data[i]);
            }

        });
```

The parsedata.php code:

```
<?php     
    include 'session.php';

   $query = "SELECT itinerary_link.itineraryID, itinerary_link.coursesID, itinerary_courses.coursename, 
courses.lat, courses.lng FROM itinerary_link LEFT JOIN
 itinerary_courses ON itinerary_link.coursesID = itinerary_courses.coursesID LEFT JOIN 
courses ON courses.coursename = itinerary_courses.coursename WHERE itineraryID=6 ORDER BY coursename";
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   $rows = array();
   while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $rows[] = $r;
   }
   print json_encode( $rows );
?>
```

And sample output from this:

```
[{"itineraryID":"6","coursesID":"20","coursename":"Carnoustie Championship Course","lat":"56.497414","lng":"-2.720531"},{"itineraryID":"6","coursesID":"21","coursename":"Troon Old Course","lat":"55.534203","lng":"-4.642833"}]
```

Basically I can't work out how to manipulate this output to create the required javascript array of lat/lngs to feed in as the waypoints for a directions service instance I have running on the page.

As always, any pointers much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: The requirements on the array for further processing is only known to yourself, unless you tell us.

Comment: @amadeus I'm sorry if my initial question hasn't fully clarified what I'm trying to achieve. To paraphrase form the google reference material: waypoints[] specifies an array of DirectionsWaypoints. Waypoints alter a route by routing it through the specified location(s). A waypoint is specified as an object literal with the following fields: location specifies the location of the waypoint, either as a LatLng or as a String which will be geocoded. stopover is a boolean which indicates that the waypoint is a stop on the route, which has the effect of splitting the route into two routes.

Comment: And @amadeus it's the getting coordinates out of my current data and into the new array that I can't do. Hope this makes more sense. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //create an array for the waypoints
  var waypoints=[];

    //only up to 8 waypoints are allowed without business-license
  for(var i=0;i<8 && i<data.length;++i) {

      //push a LatLng-object to the array
    waypoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat,data[i].lng));
  }
    //use the waypoints
  //doSomethingWith(waypoints);
```